# How can i separate the user triggered and program triggered on textbox1_TextChange Event in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using C# .net 4.0 VS 2010.

I'm trying to make a textbox that emulates facebook behavior, particular there is "+Enter Message" on a textbox and is colored gray. I also swapped the tabindex so the textbox does not selected by default (destroying the illusion).

Supposedly when the user clicked on the textbox the textbox.text disappears then the Forecolor back to black.

What happens is, it detects my program changes i put on Form_Load and runs the Event even before it's displayed.

How can i separate the user triggered and program triggered on textbox1_TextChange Event.

Here is my code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        //facebook illusion
        this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCCCCC");
        this.textBox1.Text = "+Enter Message";

    }

    //when the user clicks on the textbox
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (this.textBox1.Text.Trim() == "+Enter Message")
        {
            this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Just for Reference this is the final working codes-------------

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        //facebook illusion
        this.textBox1.TextChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
        this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCCCCC");
        this.textBox1.Text = "+Enter Message";
        this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
        this.textBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Click);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.textBox1.Text.Trim() == "+Enter Message")
        {
            this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.textBox1.Text.Trim() == "+Enter Message")
        {
            this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the events by removing the handle first

```
this.textBox1.TextChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

then adding it again or just adding the event after the text has ben changed in form_load

```
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe the `TextChanged` event after the initialization, for example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    //facebook illusion
    this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCCCCC");
    this.textBox1.Text = "+Enter Message";
    this.textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
    this.textBox1.Text = "";        
}
```

And remove it from the designer. Alternatively you can set up the `ForeColor` and the `Text` "+Enter message" directly in the designer, in this way the initialization is done before the TextChanged event subscribing.

Comment: it still gives same problem sir

Comment: which case did you try?

Comment: did you unsubscribe the TextChanged event from the designer like I've suggested?

Comment: i don't know what unsubscribe means. new in C#

Comment: Go to the designer (where you see your form in the Visual Studio), select the textbox; there should be a "Property" panel on the right. On the top of the panel you should have a "lightning" button that brings you to the "events" part of the textbox, you should press this button and search for the TextChanged and remove the textbox1_TextChanged text.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33530/discussion-between-trippino-and-henry-hughes)

Comment: it's ok sir, i think it be easier to use @Visu suggested solution. Thanks for the time.